# Can a Fourier transform be performed on irregularly sampled data with timestamps?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Normally, when I think of performing a Fourier transform, I imagine that my samples are spaced regularly in time (or space).

If I have a set of samples that are spaced irregularly, but have accurate timestamps, is it still possible to perform a Fourier transform?

Comment: I would guess this is what [trigonometric interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation) is all about, but I am no specialist. One thing I am sure is that FFT (the *fast Fourier transform* algorithm) does not apply here.

Answer (score 4):

How to do this in a fast way is explained in
Plonka et al., "Fast Fourier Transforms for Nonequispaced Data", in Numerical Fourier Analysis pp 377-419, https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-04306-3_7

Comment: Huh! Now there is not even a single thing I am sure. Interesting!

Comment: @MISC {382541, TITLE = {Can a Fourier transform be performed on irregularly sampled data with timestamps?}, AUTHOR = {[seopaslaugos](https://seosprendimai.lt/seo-paslaugos/) (https://mathoverflow.net/users/101157/bastian-seifert)}, HOWPUBLISHED = {MathOverflow}, NOTE = {URL:https://mathoverflow.net/q/382541 (version: 2021-01-29)}, EPRINT = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/382541}, URL = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/382541}
}
Very interesting, thanks for sharing!